# RoR + XAMPP + MySQL -- Gem Install MySQL Issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am PHP developer by trade and I work with XAMPP.  I have decided to dive into Ruby now and I want to use the MySQL installation from XAMPP for Ruby and I am having a problem getting the Gem for mysql to install properly.

The command I am executing is this:

```
sudo gem install mysql -- —–with-mysql-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config
```

and the error I get is this:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150126-99463-2b5bwp.rb extconf.rb 
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... yes
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib'
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling mysql.c
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib'
linking shared-object mysql/mysql_api.bundle
ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql_api.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/mysql-2.9.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql (2.9.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql -v '2.9.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

If I do a `locate mysql_config`, I get this:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config_editor
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/man/man1/mysql_config.1
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/man/man1/mysql_config_editor.1
```

I have gone through all of the help requests on SO and I cannot find a solution to my particular problem.

Any help would be appreciated.  Please let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use mysql2 instead of mysql.  
Here are some instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758945/cant-install-mysql2-on-mac-os-10-9

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on MacOS X High Sierra using RubyGems:

```
    gem install mysql2 -- \
        --with-mysql-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config \
        --with-mysql-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/mysql/ \
        --with-mysql-lib=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql/ \
        --with-mysql-include=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/ \
        --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Comment: my xampp doesn't have `xamppfiles\include` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out with this:

```
bundle config build.mysql --with-mysql-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config
gem install mysql2
```

my client:

```
require 'mysql2'
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "127.0.0.1", :username => "root")
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice the OP had XAMMP installed. Here is what I had to do to get this to work after installing XAMPP. I warn you that this is not elegant, but it does allow you to avoid a second installation of mysql

```
# first, fake the location of the headers
sudo ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles /usr/local/mysql
# second, let the libraries etc show up where they are expected:
cd /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql
for i in ../libmysql*; do sudo ln -s $i .; done
# and finally, one last hack for dynamic loading to work
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

I warned you that it was a bit ugly :-)